# Regex for string containing one string, but not another

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Have regex in our project that matches any url that contains the string 
"/pdf/":

```
(.+)/pdf/.+
```

Need to modify it so that it won't match urls that also contain "help"

Example:

Shouldn't match: "/dealer/help/us/en/pdf/simple.pdf"
Should match: "/dealer/us/en/pdf/simple.pdf"

Comment: What language, what style of regex, what code is being used to match?

Comment: Value can be a regular expression in the Perl5 style.

Comment: Can "help" occur after "/pdf/"? If so, should it match "/dealer/us/en/pdf/help.pdf"?

Comment: What tool are you using to match the regular expression? Are you using grep for example? Is it a programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If lookarounds are supported, this is very easy to achieve:

```
(?=.*/pdf/)(?!.*help)(.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/eL2bZ8/1).

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:^|\s)((?:[^h ]|h(?!elp))+\/pdf\/\S*)(?:$|\s)
```

First thing is match either a space or the start of a line

```
(?:^|\s)
```

Then we match anything that is not a  or `h` OR any `h` that does not have `elp` behind it, one or more times `+`, until we find a `/pdf/`, then match non-space characters `\S` any number of times `*`.

```
((?:[^h ]|h(?!elp))+\/pdf\/\S*)
```

If we want to detect `help` after the `/pdf/`, we can duplicate matching from the start.

```
((?:[^h ]|h(?!elp))+\/pdf\/(?:[^h ]|h(?!elp))+)
```

Finally, we match a  or end line/string (`$`)

```
(?:$|\s)
```

The full match will include leading/trailing spaces, and should be stripped. If you use capture group 1, you don't need to strip the ends.

[Example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sS4bF7/2)

Comment: This is very complicated and can be achieved **far** easier :)

Comment: @Jan This gives an immediately usable capture group, instead of matching a whole line. Also, because of this, it can match urls embedded in text, or just a list of urls not separated by line feeds.